Gravel border around grass and hover mower issues and advice
I added a gravel border around my garden last year but I'm not sure if I've done a correct job.
I changed my mower from a standard wheeled one to a Flymo hover mower and I've been having a few issues, and I'm a bit apprehensive as I'm wanting to add some more decorative stone on top of the existing gravel...

The existing gravel does get blown around somewhat by the hover mower - I would expect the larger decorative stone to not have as much of an issue?
I'm not sure I've done the correct depth of the border itself... While the gravel is currently just below the ground height, I'm worried that adding decorative stone on top would raise this more than is safe when mowing - Should one replace the gravel with the stone entirely?
Weeds growing in the border and how to deal with/stop this - I do have weed barrier down, however it appears that the weeds/grass is growing around or at the fringes...

Any help/advice is welcome!

Landscape fabric is not weed barrier, as you've found out. Is your gravel bed edged on all four sides? If not, then you'll always have grass incursion into the bed.

@Jurp I'm not 100% sure what you mean by the gravel bed being edged on all four sides... I've done the border around 90% of the garden so far. I dug down an amount that seemed suitable. One bordering garden has had all of their turf removed and stones laid, the other neighbour has done planters with stone and the back has a large wall, so there shouldn't be any incursion from their sidess
